# How i can realize the next mysql query on zend?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT  `* FROM  `messages` 
  ORDER BY  `message_id` DESC 
  LIMIT 15
) AS temp
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried already, where does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sub_select = $db->select();
$sub_select->from('messages');
$sub_select->order('message_id desc');
$sub_select->limit(15);

$select = $db->select();
$select->from(array('temp' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sub_select . ')')));
$select->order('message_id asc');
```

Doc : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html